# Can the value of $c$ be calculated from Relativity?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, newtonian-gravity, speed-of-light, physical-constants

I have three related questions about what theories or equations can calculate and what is an input parameter/constant to the theories. This question is not about parameter units (as another similar question) but calculations.

1. Can the value of $c$ be calculated from the theory of Relativity (or Maxwell’s equations)?
2. Can the value of $h$ be calculated from Quantum Mechanics?
3. Can the value of $G$ be calculated from Newtonian Mechanics?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deriving or justifying fundamental constants](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10709/)

Answer (score 2):

The value of c was derived by Maxwell, using his equations, ~1862. It required experimental values for two of the physical constants, ele tric permittiviy and magnetic permeability.   You can also calculate $ c=sqrt (E/m), from Special Relativity,  but now you must measure the energy derived from a change in mass. Both of these calculations have been done to high precision, though they are now considered only as confirmation of theory.

Each of the fundamental constants can be calculated from experimental data that is plugged into fundamental equations, though the logic chain from experiment to value may be quite involved.

But you cannot solve the equations without any experimental data.

Comment: Thanks Peter. As a follow-up, would a theory of everything predict the values of the constants?

Comment: Best ask this as a new question ...